# Is an iOS app sale considered taxable income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, sweden

This year I sold an iOS app to a company in Sweden. I was wondering how taxes work 
1 with a mobile app sale?
2 how does it being an international transaction affect its taxation?
(I’m in the United States)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is INCOME - the IRS generally does not care where the money does come from. That income is taxes in your country of residence, or - in case of US citizens and one African country - your world income even if you do not live in that country.